# Fatal error: Declaration of TableDisplayOptions::load() must be compatible with that of JTableInterface::load()

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am working on Joomla 3.3.1 and a component named JTAG Members Directory (little bit old version). I am facing the following error when I try to enter the `Display Options` section of the component:

`Fatal error: Declaration of TableDisplayOptions::load() must be compatible with that of JTableInterface::load() in /home1/nm534555/public_html/mywebsite.org/administrator/components/com_jtagmembersdirectory/tables/displayoptions.php on line 139`

When I open this file and locate line 139, I can see only the closing brace `}` as shown in the following code (whole displayoptions.php file):

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class TableDisplayOptions extends JTable
{

  var $id;
  var $display_phone_no;
  var $display_facebook_page;
  var $display_twitter_page;
  var $display_in_frontend;
  var $display_nr_email;
  var $display_nr_country;
  var $display_nr_city;
  var $display_nr_state;
  var $display_nr_phone_no;
  var $display_nr_facebook;
  var $display_nr_twitter;  
  //end

  /**
   * Contains user data from joomla users table
   * 
   * @var array $userdata
   */
  var $display;

  /**
   * Collection of custom fields objects. If custom fields are less than allowed array is filled with TableCustomFields objects
   * 
   * @var array Collection of custom fields rows
   */
  var $custom_fields;

  /**
   * Number of custom fields allowed.
   */
  const CF_ALLOWED = 10;

  function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__jtmb_display_options', 'id', $db);
   // $this->_retrieveOptions();
    $this->_retrieveCustomFields();
    }

  function load($oid=null)
  {
    parent::load($oid);
    $this->_retrieveCustomFields();
  }

  function bind($from, $ignore = array())
  {
    //checkboxes workaround
//    if(!isset($from['display_last_name'])) $from['display_last_name'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_city'])) $from['display_city'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_phone_no'])) $from['display_phone_no'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_facebook_page'])) $from['display_facebook_page'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_twitter_page'])) $from['display_twitter_page'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['cat_id'])) $from['cat_id'] = 0;
    //added by Pratik Munot
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_email'])) $from['display_nr_email'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_country'])) $from['display_nr_country'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_city'])) $from['display_nr_city'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_state'])) $from['display_nr_state'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_phone_no'])) $from['display_nr_phone_no'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_facebook'])) $from['display_nr_facebook'] = 0;
    if(!isset($from['display_nr_twitter'])) $from['display_nr_twitter'] = 0;

    //end
    if(!isset($from['display_gallery'])) $from['display_gallery'] = 0; 
    if(isset($from['auto_sync'])) $from['auto_sync'] = 1;
    parent::bind($from, $ignore);

    $this->_retrieveCustomFields();
  }

  function _retrieveOptions()
  {

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `#__jtmb_display_options';

    $this->_db->setQuery($query);

    $this->display = $this->_db->loadObject();


  }

  function _retrieveCustomFields()
  {

  //  $fields = array();

 //  $k = $this->_tbl_key;

//    if ($this->$k)
  //  {
      $query = 'SELECT field_name, field_label, display_nr_cf FROM #__jtmb_custom_fields LIMIT '.self::CF_ALLOWED;

      $this->_db->setQuery($query);

      $fields = $this->_db->loadObjectList();
    //}

    if (count($fields) < self::CF_ALLOWED)
    {
      require_once 'customfields.php';
      while (count($fields) < self::CF_ALLOWED)
      {
        $fields[] = new TableCustomFields($this->_db);
      }
    }

    $this->custom_fields = $fields;
  }

function delete()
  {
      $query = 'DELETE  FROM `#__jtmb_display_options';
      $this->_db->setQuery($query);

      $this->_db->loadObject();
  }

} -----------------------------> This is line 139

?>
```

I can't figure it out, I have tried to find the solution at different forums as well but to no avail. Could someone help me resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Check declaration of `JTableInterface::load()`.

Comment: Where can I check this declaration?

Comment: In a php-file where this interface is defined.

Comment: This should be defined in Joomla's core, I can't find it in component files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `TableDisplayOptions` implements interface `JTableInterface` (through `JTable` class, which `TableDisplayOptions` extends). This interface declares method `load` with certain parameters. As it's an interface, you MUST accept the same parameters as the interface defines.

As `JTable` class already implements the interface, just change `TableDisplayOptions::load()` to accept all parameters as `JTable::load()` does, and pass them to the parent's method.

Comment: Ok I understand but where exactly I need to make changes?

Comment: Do you use any IDE? In eclipse click on `load` in `parent::load()` while holding ctrl and it will take you straight to the parent method. Or just search inside joomla's directory. Then just make your definition of `load()` method the same.

Comment: I think I made it. Big thanks for clarification. Also got help from http://docs.joomla.org/JTable/load.

Comment: What I did was just added another parameter `$reset = true` in load() function declaration like `function load($oid = null, $reset = true) {`

Comment: You should change `parent::load($oid);` to `parent::load($oid, $reset);`. This method is likely called from inside other joomla classes, and if you don't pass `$reset` to parent, unexpected behaviour might occur.